# Why .page_setup.fitToPage on Openpyxl does not works?

Tags: python, openpyxl

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

download_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
# Read Excel files and do whatever you need

for excel_file_name in os.listdir(download_path):
    if excel_file_name.endswith('.xlsx'):
        excel_file_path = os.path.join(download_path, excel_file_name)
        excel_workbook = load_workbook(excel_file_path)
        sheet = excel_workbook.active

        # Check if the sheet is not null before continuing
        if sheet is None:
            raise ValueError("Failed to load the active sheet from the Excel file.")
        else:
            print("Correct sheet.")

        # Set scale-to-fit for one page
        sheet.page_setup.fitToPage = True
        sheet.page_setup.fitToHeight = False
        sheet.page_setup.fitToWidth = 1

        # Save the changes to the Excel file
        excel_workbook.save(excel_file_path)
```

I am getting this error on `sheet.page_setup.fitToPage = True`: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sheet_properties'

The file is ok and I do not know what to do with this problem.

I had try with another file, also changing the name of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the `fitToPage` attribute, you need to use the `PageSetupProperties` (tagname = "pageSetUpPr") class from the [openpyxl.worksheet.properties](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/worksheet/properties.html#PageSetupProperties) module.

```
sheet.sheet_properties.pageSetUpPr.fitToPage = True
```